# Installing Grub-Customizer gives an error

Tags: linux, grub, kali-linux

I've been trying to install Grub-Customizer but it gives an error

here is the code that I try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

here is the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grub-customizer
```

it's my source list;

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20140108-18:08] kali contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.0 _Kali_ - Official Snapshot i386 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20140108-18:08] kali contrib main non-free 
#kali repos installed 

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib

## Security updates
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://http.security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

Kali-Linux 2016.1 version

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the package manually from [Grub customizer download page](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+download)

Then go to it's directory and do

```
$ cmake . && make
```

After that, Also in directory

```
$ sudo make install
```

That should work for You :-)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/grub-customizer.dir/build.make:77: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/grub-customizer.dir/src/Model/ListCfg.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/grub-customizer.dir/src/Model/ListCfg.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/grub-customizer.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/grub-customizer.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:113: recipe for target 'a

Comment: First install those packages : * cmake
 * g++ OR gcc-c++
 * libgtkmm-3.0-dev OR gtkmm30-devel [when using the gtk-2 version you need libgtkmm-2.4-dev OR gtkmm24-devel]
 * gettext
 * libssl-dev OR openssl-devel
 * libarchive-dev OR libarchive-devel